# JavaScript Sort by date multidimensional Json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

I Have this following multidimensional array that I want to sort by loc_time.

```
var Json = [{
    "id": 5,
    "lieu_depart": "La rochelle",
    "lieu_arrivee": "Lyon",
    "condlocalisation": [{
        "id": 1,
        "longitude": "-3.120830",
        "latitude": "52.801452",
        "adresse": "Paris",
        "loc_time": "25 Jun 2012, 8:00 am"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "longitude": "2.130122",
        "latitude": "48.801408",
        "adresse": "Versailles",
        "loc_time": "15 May 2013, 6:40 pm"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "longitude": "-4.120854",
        "latitude": "53.80140",
        "adresse": "Marseille",
        "loc_time": "29 Jun 2012, 5:47 pm"
    }]
}]
```

This is my javascript code :

```
function comp(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.condlocalisation.loc_time).getTime() - new Date(b.condlocalisation.loc_time).getTime();
}

result.sort(comp);

$('body').append(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Where `result` variable is defined? I think you want to assign the sorting result to a `result` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the changes below:

```
function comp(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.loc_time).getTime() - new Date(b.loc_time).getTime();
}

result[0].condlocalisation.sort(comp);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Array to sort
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7yomm2ow/)