# Javascript multidimensional array sort by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, object

I've a parent array which has some objects in it and those objects have a property called `created_at` now I want to sort the parent array by the date.

`let parent_array = [ { id: 1, date: '2022-12-01T20:34:52.000000Z' }, { id: 2, date: '2022-12-06T20:34:52.000000Z', }, ];`

Now I want to sort `parent_array` by date value.

I tried this method

```
parent_array.filter((node: any) => {
            return node.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                return new Date(b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at);
            });
        })
```

But I'm getting an error "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)"

Thank You
Sakib

Comment: Typescript is complaining because Date is an object but you are trying to subtract them, convert them to numbers explicitly. `new Date(b.created_at).valueOf() - new Date(a.created_at).valueOf()`. But the `filter()` doesn't make any sense, and the return will always be true, so no filtering will happen

Comment: Typescript duplicate: [The left -hand and right hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274028/the-left-hand-and-right-hand-side-of-an-arithmetic-operation-must-be-of-type-a). (Always research the error you're getting first before posting a new question)

Comment: thanks everyone the issue was i weren't using the new Date().getTime() when i did use it. it started working. 

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118182/javascript-sort-by-date-multidimensional-json-array

Comment: I'm still confused. You are using `filter` which is sending a single object into a `sort`. - ahh, I just saw that you changed that in your answer below

Comment: Yeah. But now I removed the filter and it's working fine

Comment: If you're going to use Typescript take the time to make use of its typings. Always using `any` isn't helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let parent_array = [ { id: 1, date: '2022-12-01T20:34:52.000000Z' }, { id: 2, date: '2022-12-06T20:34:52.000000Z', }, ];

const tcx = (a: any, b: any) => {
        return new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime();
};

console.log(parent_array.sort(tcx));
```